# Recode "date & time variable" into two separate variables

Tags: r, datetime, reorganize

I'm a PhD student (not that experienced in R), and I'm trying to recode a string variable, called `RecordedDate` into two separate variables: a `Date` variable and a `Time` variable. I am using RStudio.

An example of values are:

```
8/6/2018 18:56
7/26/2018 10:43
7/28/2018 8:36
```

I would like to you the first part of the value (example: `08/6/2018`) to reformat this into a date variable, and the second part of the value (example: `18:56`) into a time variable.

1. I'm thinking the first step would be to create code that can break this up into two variables, based on some rule. I’m thinking maybe I can separate separate everything before the "space" into the `Date` variable, and after the "space" in the `Time` variable. I am not able to figure this out.
2. Then, I'm looking for code that would change the `Date` from a "*string*" variable to a "*date*" type variable.  I’m not sure if this is correct, but I’m thinking something like: 
   `better_date <- as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")`
3. Finally, then I would like to change the`Time` variable to a "time" type format (if this exists). Not sure how to do this part either, but something that indicates hours and minutes. This part is less important than getting the date variable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This question has been asked, and answered, many times but it may take you a moment to become more comfortable with searching.

Comment: Okay, I did search for this, but probably not very efficiently! I will look more into this before posting next time! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two immediate ways:

1. `strsplit()` on the white space
2. The proper ways:  parse, and then format back out.

Only 2. will guarantee you do not end up with hour 27 or minute 83 ...

Examples:

```
R> data <- c("8/6/2018 18:56", "7/26/2018 10:43", "7/28/2018 8:36")
R> strsplit(data, " ")
[[1]]
[1] "8/6/2018" "18:56"   

[[2]]
[1] "7/26/2018" "10:43"    

[[3]]
[1] "7/28/2018" "8:36"     

R>
```

And:

```
R> data <- c("8/6/2018 18:56", "7/26/2018 10:43", "7/28/2018 8:36")
R> df <- data.frame(data)
R> df$pt <- anytime::anytime(df$data)   ## anytime package used
R> df$time <- format(df$pt, "%H:%M")
R> df$day <- format(df$pt, "%Y-%m-%d")
R> df
             data                  pt  time        day
1  8/6/2018 18:56 2018-08-06 18:56:00 18:56 2018-08-06
2 7/26/2018 10:43 2018-07-26 10:43:00 10:43 2018-07-26
3  7/28/2018 8:36 2018-07-28 00:00:00 00:00 2018-07-28
R>
```

I often collect data in a data.frame (or data.table) and then add column by column.

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! This was extremely helpful. Didn't know about the anytime package!!

I opted for the second method.

The only thing I noticed was one of my values for the RecordedDate variable didn't recode correctly for the time variable.
The observation was "8/4/2018 8:36" 
pf recoded to "2018-08-04 00:00:00"
Therefore, time variable was "00:00"

This is not a big deal. Just wondering about this. Thank you so much though!! This was a major help!!

Comment: Standard ISO formats would have _two_ digits for months and date, that is what the default parser does (and single digit hours fail too). But you can try option `useR=TRUE` which switches to R's parser, that should work for you.

Comment: Also, by standard StackOverflow practice, you can "reward" this question by "upvoting" it (click on the upward facing triangle). You as the person who asked the question can also "accept" this answer as suitable (click on the "tick" mark), you will get karma points for that too---and it is how reward flows through the system. Happy StackOverflow-ing!

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense! I have accepted the answer! I also had upvoted the answer, but I think it said  I had less than "15 reputation" (my first time using this website), so it would not show publicly.

Comment: Thank you, and correct on the last part which I keep forgetting about--my bad.

Comment: No problem! Thank you so much again :)